# trouble redirecting mysql command output to file in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

for some reason, bash script doesn't redirect output of mysql command in following snippet to designated file.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

cmd="select * from foo > '/tmp/sample.txt'"
mysql --user=test --password=test <db name> --host=<hostname> --port=<portname> -e "$CMD"
```

above script redirect output to console instead of file

```
 #!/usr/bin/bash

    cmd="select * from foo INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/sample.txt' "
    mysql --user=test --password=test <db name> --host=<hostname> --port=<portname> -e "$CMD"
```

when I replace ">" redirection operator with "INTO OUTFILE", I'm getting Access permission error

Comment: Are you trying to save `/tmp/sample.txt` to your local machine or to the `hostname` where the MySQL instance is running?

Comment: Please see [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (avoid putting commands in variables).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What if you move the redirection operator (`>`) out of the quotation marks?

```
cmd="select * from foo"
mysql --user=test --password=test <db name> --host=<hostname> --port=<portname> -e "$cmd" > /tmp/sample.txt
```